# Attribution of a photo under the "GNU Free Documentation License 1.2"

Tags: copyright, licensing, attribution

What would be a way for attributing a photo using the GNU Free Documentation License 1.2 only?

Hypothetically, would this be one way? :

“Image by Jon Proctor. Retrieved June 24, 2020, from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Boeing_727-251(Adv),_Northwest_Airlines_JP6401202.jpg. This file is licensed under the GNU Free Documentation License, Version  1.2 or any later  version published by the Free Software Foundation http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:GNU_Free_Documentation_License; with no invariant Sections, no Front-Cover Texts, and no Back-CoverTexts.”

Comment: Could I get some type of response?